# Ratio test for summation of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I have a series $\sum_{n}a_n$ that diverges, is the following statement true?

$\sum_n{b_n}$ also diverges if $\forall n$ the ratio $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} > \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Assume that both series are positive and monotonic.

I can't think of a counter example but this isn't a standard ratio test as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From
$$
\frac{b_2}{b_1}
\cdot
\frac{b_3}{b_2}
\cdots
\frac{b_{n-1}}{b_{n-2}}
\cdot
\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}
>
\frac{a_2}{a_1}
\cdot
\frac{a_3}{a_2}
\cdots
\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}
\cdot
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}
$$
we get
$$b_n > \left({\small{\frac{b_1}{a_1}}}\right)a_n$$
for all $n > 1$, hence
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty b_n > \left({\small{\frac{b_1}{a_1}}}\right)\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n$$
which diverges.